# The issue of Jdiameter

Tags: java, linux, windows, tcp, diameter-protocol

```
org.jdiameter.api.RouteException: Unable to find valid connection to peer[172.17.13.31] in realm[exchange.example.org]
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.router.RouterImpl.getPeer(RouterImpl.java:381)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.controller.PeerTableImpl.sendMessage(PeerTableImpl.java:200)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.StackImpl.sendMessage(StackImpl.java:471)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.BaseSessionImpl.genericSend(BaseSessionImpl.java:202)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.BaseSessionImpl.genericSend(BaseSessionImpl.java:168)
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.SessionImpl.send(SessionImpl.java:110)
```

I used the Jdiameter of a client of Windows and tried to connect the server's Jdiameter of Linux,but I failed.
The Jdiameter's port of Linux is open, I can use the telent to access it, but I cannot use the client to connect it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the source code of  of Jdiameter,

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stacktrace, it is telling you the reason:

```
org.jdiameter.api.RouteException: Unable to find valid connection to peer[172.17.13.31] in realm[exchange.example.org]
    at org.jdiameter.client.impl.router.RouterImpl.getPeer(RouterImpl.java:381)
```

You do not have the target peer configured in your peer table . Diameter Transport requires that any Diameter node  be "routable" by current Diameter node only if we either have a direct transport connection to it  , or have a connection to a node which is.

Please provide your peer table entries for us to be able to help more.